# How to discover events for event dispatcher

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I want to write an implementation of EventSubscriberInterface for an event in commerce, there is a handy [example](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/code-recipes/state-transition), but

1. How do I find out what events are available (as a whole for my site) and/or
2. How do I know what events are getting hit on a request?

This question is not specific to the commerce module, it is just the context of my current problem.

Comment: \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the Drupal console.

List all the events that could be debugged:

`drupal debug:event`

`drupal dev`

Show the information for the specific event, for example "commerce_order.commerce_order.update":

`drupal dev commerce_order.commerce_order.update`

Answer (score 2):

I was stumped by this for a while, so I was pleased to find an answer in the Devel module

Install the Devel module and look at the toolbar menu item:

"Events info" which links to /devel/events

So for the commerce events I can see the following:

```
Callable    Priority
commerce_order.place.post_transition
Drupal\commerce_order\EventSubscriber\OrderReceiptSubscriber::sendOrderReceipt  0

commerce_order.place.pre_transition
Drupal\commerce_cart\EventSubscriber\OrderEventSubscriber::finalizeCart 0
Drupal\commerce_order\EventSubscriber\TimestampEventSubscriber::onPlaceTransition   1
Drupal\commerce_order\EventSubscriber\OrderNumberSubscriber::setOrderNumber 2
```

Comment: Thanks @Duncanmoo, today you saved my life!!!